# How to ignore certain directories while synchronizing in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I use samba to mount remote directory locally to use IntelliJ IDEA, but my project contains many large files, and they do not need to be used by IntelliJ IDEA. Luckily, the files are put under several directories, so maybe I can ignore these directories to speed up synchronizing process. I failed to find any setting about this features. It is such a pain to wait several minutes before actually do anything. Does IntelliJ IDEA support such feature? How can I enable it?

Comment: Have you ever tried mark these directories as **Excluded**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to **Mark Directory** as **Excluded**. Even though below link is for CLion, I believe, it works in a similar way in Intellij as well.
https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/12/mark-dir-as/

[image: Mark Directory Excluded]

Comment: Ah, I didn't tried right click the directory, only tried finding setting in Preferences.